# Python print statement ambiguity

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I am running the following print statement in a file test.py within the Eclipse PyDev environment which gives the required output:

```
print(f"Epoch {j}: {self.evaluate(test_data)} / {n_test}")
```

However, when I attempt to run the same code from the file at the command prompt (OSX Terminal), I get the following

```
% python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    import simple_nn
  File "/Users/davidklemitz/eclipse-workspace/_neural/simple_nn.py", line 47
    print(f"Epoch {j}: {self.evaluate(test_data)} / {n_test}")
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anybody have some clues to resolve the issue, thanks ?

Comment: What does `python --version` say?

Comment: `python` most likely points towards Python 2.

Comment: The default Python version on MacOS 11 is still Python 2. Are you using that?

Comment: Thanks all. Why was the question marked -1 !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use two different python versions in Eclipse and your terminal. Try

```
python3 test.py
```

in your terminal